# I'm trying to end my program but I don't know how to do it

Tags: python, break

I have tried to break the code but it just doesn't work for me.

If anyone knows how to break, I would be very thankful if you could help me out.

```
for n in range(50):
    x = randint(-200, 200)
    y = randint(-200, 200)
    beglys.penup()
    beglys.clear()
    beglys.goto(x, y)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hello @lenta , could you clarify your question please, if you want to break your loop you can use the [`break`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_break.asp) keyword but I think there's a condition you want to be met before breaking your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 for n in range(50):
        x = randint(-200, 200)
        y = randint(-200, 200)
        beglys.penup()
        beglys.clear()
        beglys.goto(x, y)
        time.sleep(1)
        if x:#Set on x your break condition
            break
```

Comment: Thank you for the help i figured out the rest. I was writing "if" not seperated from the edge.

Comment: Can u check it as solved?I cant post my issue unitl i resolve another